# How to filter based on text of 2 labels of tableview using UISearchController in swift?

Tags: swift

I have a tableview as shown in the picture below:

[image]

I want the filtering to happen based on both the labels in each cell of the Tableview. The result must be in the form of 2 labels .ie:if user searches for N it must displa NewYork ,Ny and print in the first cell ,Los AngelesCA and Nishat in the second and so on.Filter must filter both the arrays.Can we filter 2 arrays like in the below code:

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {

```
        filteredData =  data.filter({(dataString: String) -> Bool in
            return dataString.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil
        })

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Can we pass 2 arrays to the filter? Or what method should I use to do the same?

Comment: It would be better to change the way you handle your data source, an NSArray of NSDictionary for instance, where a dictionary would handle the two values.

Comment: Create a new array of strings where each element is the other two strings together, then filter based on that new array.

Comment: Thanks Emilio for the solution